# How to output posts from the last

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Friends help me get posts starting from the last one to the first. I'm new to RoR so help please...[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpqHN.png) - posts

[Post controller(code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qvvis.png)

Comment: `Post.order(created_at: :desc)`

Comment: It is very basic. I suggest you to please first go through [Rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/)
Before asking do some Google thing and show what you tried and error you got
`Post.order(created_at: :desc)`

Comment: For any code related questions that you have, please include code examples supporting your question

Comment: Do not use a screenshot, paste in the code.

Comment: How use Post.order(create_at: :desc)???

Comment: Just like you are using `Post.all` in your previous screenshot copy this and paste into your terminal .
Please follow this to write code in SO [format using markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ndn has noted, you just need to run `Post.order(created_at: :desc)` in the Rails console.

It's part of ActiveRecord which comes with Rails. You can read more about it here: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering